# Join two tables with no link - i.e. primary key in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I would like to know how to query two tables with no primary key link. The tables are from the same database and I need to match treenotediscription to employeeid so the results come back true at the moment I'm getting a lot of duplicate and untrue values, I think this is because of no link. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEECODE, 
    TREENODEDESCRIPTION.TREENODEDESCRIPTION2
FROM         
    EMPLOYEE 
CROSS JOIN
    TREENODEDESCRIPTION
ORDER BY 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEECODE
```

Comment: Why are you using Cross Join?

Comment: I'm using a cross join because the DBMS wont allow me to use another type of join. I've quickly just created this in design query editor and it come up with the same join?

Comment: Don't use the Query Designer. Just click New Query and type the query in the editing window.

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is a Cartesian join returning all rows. Regardless of primary or foreign keys, you need to specify which columns to join on.

Check out this article for more information about joins:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In a `CROSS JOIN` every single record in one table is joined ot every single record in the other table.  If each table has 10 records, this gives 100 resulting matches.

A more common join is an `INNER JOIN`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  employee.EmployeeCode,
  TreeNodeDescription.TreeNodeDescription2
FROM
  Employee
INNER JOIN
  TreeNodeDescription
    ON Employee.EmployeeID = TreeNodeDescription.TreeNodeDescription2
```

You specify how you want to relate the tables yourself, the existance of Foreign or Primary Keys doesn't automate this for you.  They merely serve to enforce certain rules on the database, to keep it in a consistent state.

Comment: You guys are good! This query above will work however it maybe my database at fault, it has return no values :(

Comment: As you say, it's probably that the values in EmployeeID don't match the values in TreeNodeDescription2.

Comment: @Tyrone2011: You could replace INNER JOIN with FULL JOIN. That way you'll be able to see all the values from both tables. If they match, they'll appear on the same row, if not then one of the columns will contain NULL. If there are indeed no matches between the two tables, all the rows will contain one value and one NULL, but at least you'll get the chance to see with your eyes why there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no requirement to have a relational link on columns to perform a join.  Joins are based on boolean conditions.  If the boolean condition is true, then the join happens.

That said, I suspect your real problem here is the type of join you are using.  A CROSS JOIN will join every match on both sides against every other match.  Depending on what you're after, you are more likely to need an INNER or LEFT join.

Answer (score 0):

Just JOIN on the common field - no FK or other relationship needed!!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     e.EmployeeCode,
     t.TreeNodeDescription2
FROM         
    dbo.Employee e
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TreeNodeDescription t ON e.EmployeeID = t.TreeNodeScription
ORDER BY 
    e.EmployeeCode
```